# getting segmentation fault with Point2f

Tags: opencv

I have extracted some feature points of an image using the following code

```
vector<Point2f> cornersFrame1;
goodFeaturesToTrack( frame1, cornersFrame1, maxCorners, qualityLevel, minDistance, Mat(), blockSize, useHarrisDetector, k );
```

After that i want to read the values of present at these feature points. So, i am using the following code:

```
for(int i=0; i<cornersFrame1.size(); i++)
{       
    float frame1 = calculatedU.at<float>( cornersFrame1[i].x, cornersFrame1[i].y     ); 
}
```

then i get Segmentation fault.

But if i use the following code in "For loop" then it work.

```
    float frame1 = calculatedU.at<float>( cornersFrame1[i].y, cornersFrame1[i].x     );
```

**I am confused because i think that "Point2f" stores pixel information as (row , col). Isn't it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not. All types of points in OpenCV are just normal points that you can think about: (x,y). When it comes to coordinate in image this means that 'x' is a column and 'y' is a row. On the other hand at<> requires as input (row, column). This is why you had to provide (y,x) instead of (x,y).

Just to prevent future confusion, one of the ways of using at<> is this one:

```
float frame1 = calculatedU.at<float>( cornersFrame1[i] );
```

This way you don't need to think whether you should provide (x,y) or (y,x).

Comment: to explain why this is a little bit confusing: Matrices are sorted row-first by math convention, while images, plots and other "points" are sorted x-first.